# SQLite syntax error near "%"

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax-error

I get this error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, word, meaning FROM todo WHERE KEY_WORD = +%D9%84
```

for this

```
database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, "KEY_WORD = " +word, null, null,
            null, null,null);
```

when word is +%D9%84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the SQL query. To do this, use the `selectionArgs` field (right after `"KEY_WORD = " +word` in your code). It will replace any `?` in the selection field with its elements:

```
database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
  KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, KEY_WORD + " = ?", new String[] { word },
  null, null, null, null);
```

For more details, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I am sure that have the record but android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_WORD: , while compiling: SELECT _id, word, meaning FROM todo WHERE KEY_WORD = ?

Comment: @Hamhame this is probably because `KEY_WORD` should be put outside the quotation marks (if it is a constant containing the name of the column) - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the word with`"` characters. If you want to use wildcards, you have to use the `like` comparison operator instead of `=`.